# Java happens-before relationship?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, happens-before

Consider the following code.

```
public class Test {
    private boolean running = false;

    public void run() {
        running = true;
    }

    public void test() {
        boolean running1 = running;
        boolean running2 = running;
        System.out.println("running1: " + running1);
        System.out.println("running2: " + running2);
    }
}
```

Thread A calls `run()`, then another thread B calls `test()` and there shouldn't be any happens-before relationship. I know it is not guaranteed that thread B sees the changes which thread A made. But is it possible that the output of this program is:

```
running1: true
running2: false
```

Comment: This is almost my question, but not exectly. In the suggested answer two different variables are used. However I only read from one variable. So the answer is: This doesn't answer my question completely. **Edit:** https://stackoverflow.com/q/16213443/3882565 was suggested.

Comment: "But is it possible that [...]": yes, it is (whatever "[...]" is). The behavior of the program is undefined, so literally anything can happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, because it's not explicitly forbidden.

The read of `running` for the assignments to `running1` and `running2` can happen in any order with respect to each other, and the read for `running2` could happen after the first `System.out.println`. And there's nothing to say that either of the reads should be from cache or main memory.

Basically, it's very open as to what that can print (and why).

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped a lot, but now I have another question. What if i replace it by `boolean running1 = running;    boolean running2;    if (running1) { running2 = running; }`. Now it seems like it can't be reordered, or can it? It would be nice if you can also cover this case in your answer.